Transfrom Update in Delete Insert Oracle Golden Gate
I have a Oracle GoldenGate extract verions 19.21.0.0.231017 and a Oracle GoldenGate for Big Data replicat Version 21.9.0.0.3, i want to trasform every UPDATE in 2 transaction DELETE and INSERT.
There is any possibility to do that with extract and replicat parameters?

Could you please add more details on why you need such a request? Maybe further logic can be added on a target side? Consider giving a look at INSERTUPDATES. In this case you can add extra column containing source type of operation to detect updates and add some extra logic to handle this operation on target
